# Hiding Fragment and showing other Fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on an Android App and trying to hide one Fragment and showing another Fragment. I have been stuck in this for two days now, as I tried every possibility, googled a lot - however it is not delivering the desired result:

```
 package com.cubic.cumo.rmvsmt.fragments;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.cibo.Cibo;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.cibo.CiboJourney;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.common.CumoTextTools;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.fragments.BasisFragment;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.fragments.FragmentCreator;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.fragments.UiContent;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.model.StopInfo;
    import com.cubic.cumo.basislib.model.TicketInfo;
    import com.cubic.cumo.rmvsmt.MainActivity;
    import com.cubic.cumo.rmvsmt.R;

    public class RMVCiboJourneyFragment extends BasisFragment {

        /**
         * Fragment creator for the RMV Station Selector.
         */
        public static class Creator extends FragmentCreator {

            @Override
            public BasisFragment create(String name, Bundle args) {
                RMVCiboJourneyFragment f = new RMVCiboJourneyFragment();
                f.setArguments(args);
                return f;
            }
        }

        private View mContentNoJourney;
        private View mContentJourney;
        private TextView mOriginTextView;
        private TextView mDestinationTextView;
        private TextView mDepartureTextView;
        private TextView mArrivalTextView;

        private CiboJourney mJourney;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cibo_journey, container, false);

            mContentJourney =       view.findViewById(R.id.content_journey);
            mContentNoJourney =     view.findViewById(R.id.content_no_journey);
            mOriginTextView =       view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_journey_origin_text);
            mDestinationTextView =  view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_journey_destination_text);
            mDepartureTextView =    view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_journey_departure_text);
            mArrivalTextView =      view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_journey_arrival_text);

            Button okButton = view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_ok_button);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    getActivity().setResult(0);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
            Button onReportErrorButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cibo_report_error_button);
            onReportErrorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getActivity().setResult(1);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            try {
                mJourney = (CiboJourney) bundle.getSerializable("DATA");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // This will catch any exception, because they are all descended from Exception
                System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            if (mJourney != null && mJourney.arrival != null && mJourney.departure != null && mJourney.origin != null && mJourney.destination != null) {
                mContentJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                mOriginTextView.setText(mJourney.origin.getName());
                mDepartureTextView.setText(getString(R.string.cibo_start_station, CumoTextTools.formatDate(mJourney.departure, CumoTextTools.CumoDateFormat.TIME)));
                mDestinationTextView.setText(mJourney.destination.getName());
                mArrivalTextView.setText(getString(R.string.cibo_dest_station, CumoTextTools.formatDate(mJourney.arrival, CumoTextTools.CumoDateFormat.TIME)));
            } else {
                mContentJourney.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.getId();
            }

            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public void showContent(UiContent content) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onBackPressed() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the View that should show up in the other Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    try {
        mJourney = (CiboJourney) bundle.getSerializable("DATA");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // This will catch any exception, because they are all descended from Exception
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    if (mJourney != null && mJourney.arrival != null && mJourney.departure != null && mJourney.origin != null && mJourney.destination != null) {
        mContentJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mOriginTextView.setText(mJourney.origin.getName());
        mDepartureTextView.setText(getString(R.string.cibo_start_station, CumoTextTools.formatDate(mJourney.departure, CumoTextTools.CumoDateFormat.TIME)));
        mDestinationTextView.setText(mJourney.destination.getName());
        mArrivalTextView.setText(getString(R.string.cibo_dest_station, CumoTextTools.formatDate(mJourney.arrival, CumoTextTools.CumoDateFormat.TIME)));
    } else {
        mContentJourney.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.getId();
    }

    return view;
}
```

This is the code in the other Fragment that should do mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or at least show the corresponding view:

```
 if ((backButton != null) && (closeButton != null)) {
                    backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "closeButton geklickt");

                            RMVCiboJourneyFragment nextFrag= new RMVCiboJourneyFragment();
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.WebContentWebView, nextFrag, "mContentNoJourney")
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();
                            //mContentNoJourney =     view.findViewById(R.id.content_no_journey);
                            //mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             /*     *//*      List<Fragment> fragmentList = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentFactory.instance().registerCreator(FragmentFactory.CiboJourney, new RMVCiboJourneyFragment.Creator());
                            FragmentTransaction transaction;
                            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();*//*
                            //transaction.replace(R.id.container,R.id.content_no_journey);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            transaction.commit();*/

                         /*   Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag();
                            if(fragment != null)
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();*/

                            // FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                            // fm.popBackStack();
                            // You might have to access all the fragments by their tag,
                            // in which case just follow the line below to remove the fragment
                            /*if (fragmentList == null) {
                                // code that handles no existing fragments
                            }
                            for (Fragment frag : fragmentList )
                            {
                                // To save any of the fragments, add this check
                                // a tag can be added as a third parameter to the fragment when you commit it
                               *//* if (frag.getTag().equals("<tag-name")) {
                                    continue;
                                }*//*
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
                            }

                            Fragment id = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                            if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container) == null) {
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.titlebar, id)
                                        .commit();
                            }
                            RMVCiboJourneyFragment journeyFragment = new RMVCiboJourneyFragment();
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_no_journey, journeyFragment).commit();*/
                            //mContentNoJourney = getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(R.id.content_no_journey);
                            //mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The problem is, that none of what I have commented out is working.

I am basically just trying to shut down a Fragment in a Webview and open up another Fragment, which is not working.

Any hints or help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `show/hide` try to replace fragment based on condition using Fragment Transaction

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman: Thanks a lot - can you provide an example on how to do that? I tried it in the code that is commented out, that didn´t worked - any help or hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not clear about your requirements. Do you want to replace  `R.id.WebContentWebView` with this `RMVCiboJourneyFragment `? Am I right?

Comment: Well, in fact I want to do/show  mContentJourney.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContentNoJourney.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); which is working perfectly in one Fragment but not in the other

Comment: It is not clear how your app/structure look like (mainly what is mentioned `WebContentWebView` view) anyway I may suggest to insert into layout single match_parent/match_parent `FrameLayout` and insert and replace your fragments in this container. Your replace method over `FragmentManager` looks correct so issue should be on different place.